# What kind of structure is this?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I have written this paragraph as part of a review. I believe it is correct grammar but can't pinpoint the logic behind the use of the comma or the ***it is***.  I don't know the name of this kind of structure or usage. Can anyone help?

*A black comedy that at times evolves into a tense thriller and at others shows hints of horror, **it is** an original, gripping, and disturbing tale of pervasive class tension, oppression, and helplessness.*

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you wrote the passage, what logic made you add the comma and _it is_? I'd put a full stop where the comma is and have it as two sentences.

Comment: The problem is I think it sounds correct but I don't know why! I don't think a full stop would work there. "A black comedy" doesn't have its own verb. Since in the first part of the sentence I have a noun phrase and then a subordinate adjective clause it seemed more correct to put a comma and then add the verb.

Comment: *Non-native speaker* The introductory noun phrase "A black comedy.." can be thought of as a reduced clause (following the terminology used in The Cambridge Grammar of the English language - "verbless clause"). It is predicated of the subject "It" in the main clause. Other forms (especially participial clauses) are more common in this position. There is a set phrase "N + as X is/was." that resembles your sentence : (from Oliver Twist) : "Child as he was, he was desperate with hunger, and reckless with misery."

Comment: I have now realized that if I invert the order of the sentence it works better: "It is an original, gripping, and disturbing tale of pervasive class tension, oppression, and helplessness, a black comedy that at times evolves into a tense thriller and at others shows hints of horror." Do you think the original is correct? Thanks for your insight Rejlan Givens.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the question was meant for me Rocio, but my answer (as a non-native speaker) is yes. It is not ungrammatical, that's for sure. Hope you get a more definitive answer from other contributors :)

Comment: It's two complete sentences joined by a comma.  A semicolon or period would be more appropriate.

Comment: (Referring to the 1st version of your question).  The problem at this end of your question is the absence of context.  I assume that the play gets named, and that therefore The pronoun ‘it’ has something to refer to.  If you supply the context you would allow a properly informed answer.  My initial comment (without context I cannot do more, is that the gap between ‘it’ and the play it refers to is far too great.  But this use of a participle phrase (or is it ‘clause’ nowadays?) as a way of ‘laying the foundations for the main statement.  Here, the use seems explanatory.

Comment: The skeletal sentence is "A black comedy..... is an original, gripping and disturbing tale ....." No need for 'it' here.

Comment: @RamPillai - That’s not the skeletal sentence.  That sentence defines what a black comedy is.  OP’s sentence is describing an unnamed play(?) as being a black comedy; one that at times evolves into a into ...

Answer (score 1):

The sentence from the OP illustrates the use of a highly versatile and common syntactic construction, which in simple terms can be described as: Predicate + Main Clause. Here's another sentence illustrating this syntactic pattern:

> "A long-time favorite of critics, Timothy Oliphant is set to win this
>   year's Oscar. "

The introductory noun phrase : "A long-time favorite of critics" ("A black comedy.." in the OP) is understood as predicated of the following NP "Timothy Oliphant". Or, to put it differently, the introductory NP has a clausal character. (if you wish, you can call it "I'll borrow the subject from the main clause" construction")

Now, here's the same sentence, with an added comma, representing a case of apposition:

> "A long time favorite of critics, Timothy Oliphant, is set to win this
>   year's Oscar."

The intention here is quite different - we want to precisely specify the person/thing that is "a long time favorite of critics". Apposition, thus, is a term used for a concept/idea/construction with a far narrower meaning and use. We can predicate anything about anyone or anything, in any possible syntactic form, while apposition is a quite limited concept, both semantically and formally. 
What strikes first from the sentences illustrating apposition is that the appositive pattern is fixed: "NP comma NP comma" - the appositive modifier is set off by commas (with the exception of two examples from CGEL illustrating detached appositive modifiers as a minor usage ) Not only that, the order is fixed too: anchor + appositive modifier. This sharply contrasts with the other construction explained here. The ascriptive NP from the first sentence is almost free-floating - we can move it around like: *"Timothy Oliphant, a long-time favorite of critics, is set to win this year's Oscar"* (again, this is not a case of apposition).

I found a thorough treatment of apposition in Quirk's "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language". I've read the part concerning what the authors termed "non-restrictive apposition", which is at issue here: ("supplementive apposition" in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language). Here's what is said there:

> Apposition is primarily and typically a relation between two noun
>   phrases...... In non-restrictive apposition the two NPs contribute
>   relatively independent information, with the first appositive acting
>   as the DEFINED expression, and the other appositive having a DEFINING
>   role ("the definer"). The defining role is reflected in the fact that
>   the second appositive is marked as parenthetic by punctuation or
>   intonation.

Here's a useful clue : the template: "NP comma Main Clause" will never be understood as an apposition. The two adjacent NPs in this construction will never be read as "The Defined Expression + The Definer". As I said multiple times, these two NPs will be in a Subject+Predicate relation.

Another useful clue: the template: "NP comma, NP, comma" will typically, but not necessarily be an apposition. Only if the two NPs stand in the "The Defined - The Definer" relation will this construction be understood as a unique sort of a relation/construction that people termed "apposition". This example from CGEL nicely illustrates this point: "Kim Jones, a quite outstanding student, won a scholarship at MIT" . This is not a case of apposition - "a quite outstanding student" doesn't specify "Kim Jones", it "..expresses a property that is ascribed to Kim Jones". This is clearly set out in the definition provided in this grammar book: "The construction with a SPECIFYING NP as supplement is known as apposition".

As with any other syntactic construction, tons could be said about this one too. One less striking but very interesting aspect, for example, would be the use of pronouns as appositives. The appositive modifier is supposed to specify, but how can you specify something with a pronoun? "A black comedy, it, .. ". (Using "this", "that" etc. will similarly preclude this construction, e.g "this actor" instead of Timothy Oliphant in the second example above will make the sentence unreadable. Notice also that the anchor can be a pronoun: "We the supporters of.. ")

Apposition is all about being more specific about what the person has just referred to. I refer to X and then I refer to X again, only now in more specific terms. That's all there is to this construction. I believe there are good reasons for setting it apart from a superficially similar, but fundamentally different construction. We want to group similar ideas together, and to distinguish them from dissimilar ones. This is why I said earlier that we shouldn't label the NP from the OP sentence as apposition - it is not a minor terminological point. 
 It is not about one or the other term, it is about what these terms represent, and why they were introduced in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and informative answer. The CGEL makes a clear distinction between ascriptive and specifying supplements, and categorizes only the former as _apposition_. But the main point I was making in my other comments was that answers to similar questions should refer to the diversity of opinions on what constitutes _apposition_. For example, the Wikipedia (yes, I know!) article includes the following examples: _The first to arrive at the house, she unlocked the front door_ and _A staunch supporter of democracy, Rob campaigned against the king's authoritarian rule._

Comment: I would still be interested in your analysis of my reordered sentence: _It is an original, gripping, and disturbing tale of pervasive class tension, oppression, and helplessness, a black comedy that at times evolves into a tense thriller and at others shows hints of horror_ in which the _black comedy_ phrase could be regarded as a reduced non-restrictive relative clause whose antecedent is _tale_.

Comment: Hi Shoe! Interestingly, I've just been checking a couple of forum threads on appositives, and I must say that there is a lot of confusion about what the term is supposed to entail. I'll supply another answer here to point to what I believe are the main problems in defining and understanding apposition. I'll answer your questions and comment on the examples you offered. For now I'll just say that, both of the two most referred-to , and most comprehensive grammar textbooks define "apposition" as a relation of "specified-specifier". This definition makes sense to me for a number of reasons.

Comment: Reading the forum threads, I've found a number of suggestions that go against the accepted definition. Some contributors, for example, suggested thinking of it as "reduced relative clauses", which matches other analyses I came across here. Basically, people tend to understand "apposition" as anything that is found enclosed in commas, typically somewhere in the middle of the sentence. That seems to be a prevalent idea. This means that any noun phrase that follows another noun phrase and is set off by commas (or even only one comma, at the end of the sentence) is understood as apposition.

Comment: Rejlan. I look forward to your analysis of the issue. You might want, however,  to make your insights the answer to a question that you yourself ask. This is permissible here. In that way it will not be buried in this particular thread, and it will allow others to post their own thoughts and insights.

Comment: A final comment for today. As a non-linguist (except insofar as a language teacher is a linguist) the issue of terminology seems a little _no true Scotsman_ to me. If I have defined _apposition_ solely as a relation of _specified-specifier_, then I can rule out everything else that doesn't come into this category.

Comment: Good point! I already referred to it (it is  now deeply buried in the comment section). I said that the bigger mistake than defining something as apposition, when it is obviously is not, is failing to see what it is. One more example as an illustration, and I'll quit commenting (not readable this way, I agree). In this thread here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286393/is-delayed-appositive-correct-term-for-this,  the OP sentence is almost unreadable (for the reasons BillJ explained). However, it resembles your sentence, with a noun phrase coming at the end of the sentence.

Comment: (I'm finishing with this one, sorry) The term "delayed appositive" is what BillJ (who provided an imperfect but very informed answer) wouldn't mind you calling your "a black comedy.." at the end of the sentence. (your sentence is perfectly readable of course, unlike the other one) However, it is not an appositive, delayed or else. (Neither is, "a real brute of a man" in "The hunter, a real brute of a man, ..).

Answer (score -2):

Though there are various overlapping/conflicting definitions of the terms 'apposition / appositives' (see McCawley's balanced but now dated overview [McCawley: *The Syntactic Phenomena of English* ... p 467]) (and grateful thanks to @Shoe here), the following is based on one (broader) definition:

> [The] **appositive** – [usually] a noun or noun phrase that identifies[, adds description to] or renames
>   another noun – is a handy way of adding details to a sentence. The
>   term comes from the Latin word for "placing close by," and an
>   appositive usually appears right after the word or phrase that it
>   renames.
>
> [Here is] one example of an appositive [(shown in italics and set off
>   by commas)]:
>
> - He was a Hindu, *a puny wisp of a man*, with a shaven head and vague
>     liquid eyes.

[[ThoughtCo_R Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-appositive-1691027)]

....................

Showing different functions of appositives:

- A renaming example: William F Cody, *Buffalo Bill*, was an American soldier, hunter, and showman.
- An identifying example: The *Mallard*, the world's fastest steam locomotive, was built in 1938
- A descriptive example: The *Mallard*, a fine example of locomotive streamlining, can be seen at York.

(Appositives in the usual postnominal parenthetical position, set off by commas.)

....................

> *Arranging Appositives*
>
> A [nounal] appositive most often appears *directly after* the noun it
>   identifies[, adds description to] or renames:
>
> - Arizona Bill, "The Great Benefactor of Mankind," toured Oklahoma with herbal cures and a powerful liniment.
>
> Note that this appositive, like most, could be omitted without
>   changing the basic meaning of the sentence. In other words, it's
>   nonrestrictive and needs to be set off with a pair of commas.
>
> Occasionally, an appositive may appear in front of a word that it
>   identifies:
>
> - A dark wedge, the eagle hurtled earthward at nearly 200 miles per hour.
>
> An appositive at the beginning of a sentence is usually followed by a
>   comma.

[Note that descriptive appositives can hardly meaningfully replace the other noun phrase, but may do so with no compromising of syntax. With the 'Hindu' example above, one could argue as to which noun phrase is the descriptor.]

[[again, Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-build-sentences-with-appositives-1689672)]

So in

*A black comedy that at times evolves into a tense thriller and at others shows hints of horror*, **it** is an original, gripping, and disturbing tale of pervasive class tension, oppression, and helplessness.

The noun phrase (italicised) is in apposition to **it**, and precedes the [pro]noun that it in this case adds description to. The expected comma separates the sentence-initial appositive from the noun it adds description to. Note that, as mentioned in comments, 'it' must have an antecedent in the preceding sentence / fragment.

Comment: Nice to see that you are still providing English learners with your pro-bono language advice Edwin :) As for this one, I don't think that the introductory noun phrase qualifies as apposition here. The reasons for it are nicely laid out on page 1358 of CGEL, you may want to check it. In a nutshell, for it to qualify as apposition, removing the "anchor" (it) would have to mean the same as the original sentence. Here, obviously, it doesn't: A black comedy .. is a gripping.. doesn't mean the same as the original. The introductory noun phrase is an "ascriptive NP supplement".

Comment: The two examples provided on the page illustrate the point very nicely: "United will be playing at home, a not inconsiderable advantage". "A die-hard conservative, her father refused to even consider the proposal".

Comment: A question about this construction has been asked here, and was clearly and precisely answered by billj https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/absolute-structure-a-student-he.3606711/

Comment: Of course, this depends on terminology; CGEL grades more finely here (and admittedly may be a better treatment). However, CGEL doesn't rate alongside the original manuscripts of the Bible as regards authority / inerrancy. Professor Nordquist is happy to label the 'eagle' example an appositive usage. And I see the lumping of various structures under the 'intransitive preposition' heading an oversimplification, and thankfully I'm not the only one.

Comment: Applying the term apposition to unrelated concepts is not a good idea. The term appositive should be used to indicate two coreferential/equivalent phrases and nothing else. Leaving out any of the two equivalent phrases should leave the meaning intact. The sentence in the op doesn't pass that test. Not only do we make a mistake of lumping unrelated things together by calling the introductory NP apposition, more importantly, we fail to see its relation with a number of other forms  that have the same function.

Comment: The introductory phrase is predicated of the following subject "it". This noun phrase should then be categorized together with participial clauses and adjectives, which are more commonly used in this position. For example: Tired of waiting, I decided to leave. / Having nothing else to say,  I left./ A black comedy that at times evolves into a tense thriller and at others shows hints of horror, it is an original, gripping, and disturbing tale of pervasive class tension, oppression, and helplessness

Comment: @Rejlan Givens. McCawley on p. 467 of _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_ states: _"Various authors have proposed criteria for identifying a combination of two expressions as 'apposition', the most popular ones being (i) that the two expressions have identical reference; (ii) that they be of the same syntactic category; (iii) that either of them can be omitted without affecting the acceptability of the sentence; and (iv) that either of them can be omitted without affecting how the remaining constituents are interpreted."_

Comment: McCawley goes on to say: _There is little consensus as to the appropriateness of (i-iv) as criteria for 'apposition' or with regard to how to apply the criteria ..._ In view of this lack of consensus it seems that it is important,  in any discussion of the issue, to state whose definition is being used. The answer above does that, but could also make the point that this is not the only interpretation. (A more detailed answer to the present question could also discuss _fronting_ and _theme/topic_ as expounded by Halliday in _Functional Grammar_.)

Comment: Hi Shoe! The introductory phrase in the sentence from the OP is a predicate. It derives the subject from the main clause. So the difference between analyzing it as a predicate as opposed to thinking of it as an appositive is much like a difference between: "It is a black comedy" and "black comedy". The introductory phrase "A black comedy.." has a clausal character, albeit a reduced clause. The construction is extremely common in writing of course, comprising a number of different forms.

Comment: The clearest case are participial clauses like:

Being a comedy, it never gets heavy but stays on the funny side.

The so-called "absolute clause" includes the subject, and is thus a step further in shaping the participial clause into a full-blown clause:

This movie being a comedy, it never gets heavy but stays on the funny side. On the other end of the scale we have adjectives and noun phrases, which are less easily conceived as clauses:

Laugh out loud funny at times, it won't fail to thrill even the pickiest fans.

Comment: Arguably, a simple noun phrase oftentimes will not do in this position, but the more we expand it the more it feels natural. In short, I don't see this as a mere terminological point, or as nitpicking, or fine-grading, or else. This is rather about being coherent in sentence analysis.

Comment: @Rejlan Givens. Thanks for your explanations. Perhaps you could even consider expanding them into an answer. I have no horse in this particular race, and in any case I am more interested in grammaticality than classification and terminology. But I would be interested to know how you would analyse the black comedy phrase in the reordered sentence: _It is an original, gripping, and disturbing tale of pervasive class tension, oppression, and helplessness, a black comedy that at times evolves into a tense thriller and at others shows hints of horror_.

Comment: I will be glad to contribute to this forum Shoe :) As soon as I have more time, I'll try to put it together into a (hopefully) decent answer. As for your rendering of the sentence, I must say that I like the flow better than the original (which is also okay). I've never thought about the grammar of this construction, but I've often seen it used of course. I find it a very neat stylistic tool - especially to add a punch line, crescendo, an afterthought or produce a wrap-up effect.  Grammatically, it is a predicative adjunct - it is predicated of the subject "It"of course.

Comment: Predicative adjuncts are commonly used and are not necessarily detached from the rest of the sentence by a comma. "A black comedy.." in your sentence has to be of course, following the long coordination. Here's an example of an integrated predicative adjunct: He left the country a rich man. Adjectives are far more commonly used for this purpose.

Comment: @Rejlan Givens. Looking at the CGEL section on _specifying and ascriptive supplements_ (p1356), it seems to me that the _black comedy_ phrase in my reordered sentence could be seen as what CGEL calls _apposition_, namely '_a construction with a specifying NP as supplement_; in this case specifying what kind of tale it is. (But I've just been admonished to avoid extended discussions in comments, so I'll sign off here and look forward to your answer.)

Comment: @Shoe I know it's possible to access some of McCawley online free; do you please have a link? // I'd just use the appositive class again, 'It is an A,/; a B' with A and B appositive complements.

Comment: Sorry, Edwin. I have the book.